# Force custom Ranking Model

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-search

so here is my question:
I am currently working on a project, which was previously handled by multple different firms. So the code is kinda messy.

In order to rank a people-search-result I've tried the following:

I created  a custom ranking model.

After that I derived from Core Results Webpart and overridden the OnItit()-Method in order to change the DefaultRankingModelID-Property.
-> doesn't work..

In The ResultsPage-Module, where my custom ResultsWebPart is instanciated, I changed the "DefaultRankingModelID"-Property right the same way.

After that I've added the "&rm1="-Tag to the search query.

Nothing is working at all. It just ignores whatever I've tried and still sorts the result by "Employee-ID".
Strangely I am able to sort the Results. But I need to rank them by proximity, then by name, and so on...

Hope you got the idea...
Help would be really appreciated! I smashed my head at the wall like a thousand times!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the Query Properties.

This is how to do it for SharePoint 2013.If you are using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery you can assign Your rankingmodelid to keywordQuery.RankingModelId

Comment: Did the above answer worked for you? We are going through same problem